# using google maps api, how to get country, state, and city from lat and long?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I my react app, i am using the libraries `@react-google-maps/api` and `react-places-autocomplete`.

How do I get the country, state, city given lat and long coordinates?

How to get the formatted address, place, give lat and long?

Comment: What you're looking for is "reverse geocoding". https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Answer (score 1):

1. Use react-native-geocoding package for Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding.
2. install react-native-geocoding

> npm install --save react-native-geocoding

3. For Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding in your app you import **Geocoder** API from **react-native-geocoding** package like this

> import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';

4. Geocoder.init("API key"); // initialize module
5. And use this code respectively for Geocoding and reverse Geocoding

> Geocoder.from(41.89, 12.49)
> .then(json => {
> var addressComponent = >json.results[0].address_components[0];
>
> console.log(addressComponent);
> })
> .catch(error => console.warn(error));
> // location object
> Geocoder.from({
> latitude : 41.89,
> longitude : 12.49
> });
>
> ```
> // latlng object
> Geocoder.from({
>   lat : 41.89,
>   lng : 12.49
> });
>
> // array
> Geocoder.from([41.89, 12.49]);
> ```